# Optical flow implementation on esp32

Tags: c++, embedded

I am trying to implement a motion detection algorithm using state of the art on an esp32camera.
This board has 512kB RAM and I don't want to use too much CPU.
So I wanted to get a review on what I implemented if there is piece of code which could be optimized. 
I tried to comment as much as possible and put link on existing code I took and reshaped.

**Context**:

I try to implement [Lucas-Kanade optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method).

My code is composed of :

- conv : [full convolution 1D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518989/how-to-perform-1-dimensional-valid-convolution).
- transpose : rescale the input vector to 0..255 and transpose the equivalent array into a buffer.
- LK_optical_flow : The main code that perform a 2D convolution with Sobel filters and input images. Then compute optical flow magnitude.

**Code:**

```
/** Rescale vector to 0..255 and transpose
 * @param[in] src vector from convolution unscaled 
 * @param[out] dst pointer of buffer image*/
template<typename T>
void transpose(std::vector<T> src, uint8_t *dst, const int w, const int h) {    
    auto max = *std::max_element(src.begin(), src.end());
    auto min = *std::min_element(src.begin(), src.end());
    for(int n = 0; n< w * h; n++) {
        const int i = n / h;
        const int j = n % h;
        dst[n] = (uint8_t)(src[w * j + i] - min) * 255.0 / max;
    }
}

/** convolution 1D between flattened image and strel
 * from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518989/how-to-perform-1-dimensional-valid-convolution
 * @param f pointer of flattened image buffer
 * @param g structurant element (strel)
 * @return convolved image as vector*/
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> conv(uint8_t *f, const std::vector<T> &g, const int nf) {
    int const ng = g.size();
    int const n  = nf + ng - 1;
    std::vector<T> out(n, T()); 
    for(auto i(0); i < n; ++i) {
        int const jmn = (i >= ng - 1)? i - (ng - 1) : 0;
        int const jmx = (i <  nf - 1)? i            : nf - 1;
        for(auto j(jmn); j <= jmx; ++j) 
            out[i] += (f[j] * g[i - j]);
    }
    out.erase(out.begin(), out.begin() + ng / 2 + 1);  // remove edge due to full convolution
    return out;
}

/// Optical flow Lucas-Kanade
/** Implement LK optical flow source from wiki:
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method
 * @param src1 pointer to grayscale buffer image instant t
 * @param src2 pointer to grayscale buffer image diff Image between t and t+1
 * @param output Magnitude output image in RGB */
void LK_optical_flow(uint8_t *src1, uint8_t *src2, uint8_t *output, int w, int h)
{
    //Allocate 1D strel
    std::vector<int> Kernel_Dy = {1, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int> Kernel_Dx = {-1, 0, 1};
    std::vector<int> Kernel_Dt = {1, 1, 1};

    //Allocate fy only. Too much memory on the heap.
    std::vector<int> tmp; 
    uint8_t *fx = src1;
    uint8_t *fy = new uint8_t[w * h];
    uint8_t *ft = src2;

    memset(output, 0, w * h * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(fy, fx, w * h * sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Compute equivalent of 2D convolution decompose of two 1D convolution.
    // Sobel Dx
    tmp = conv(fx, Kernel_Dx, w*h);
    transpose(tmp, fx, w, h);
    tmp = conv(fx, Kernel_Dy, w*h);
    transpose(tmp, fx, w, h);   
    // Sobel Dy
    tmp = conv(fy, Kernel_Dy, w*h);
    transpose(tmp, fy, w, h);
    tmp = conv(fy, Kernel_Dx, w*h);  
    transpose(tmp, fy, w, h);   
    // Dt
    tmp = conv(ft, Kernel_Dt, w*h);
    transpose(tmp, ft, w, h);
    tmp = conv(ft, Kernel_Dt, w*h);  
    transpose(tmp, ft, w, h);   

    std::vector<int>().swap(tmp); // deallocate tmp 

    //TODO: Create a function for all above : Mag = opticalflow(fx, fy, ft, window=3)
    const int window = 3; //half window size
    float AtA[2][2];
    float Atb[2];
    std::vector<unsigned> Mag(w*h);

    // Lucas Kanade optical flow algorithm
    for(int i=window; i<=w-window;++i){
        for(int j=window; j<h-window;++j){
            memset(Atb, 0, sizeof(float) * 2);
            memset(AtA, 0, sizeof(float) * 4);
            for(int m=-window; m<window;++m){
                const unsigned index = (j + m) * w + (i + m);
                const float Ix = (float) fx[index];
                const float Iy = (float) fy[index];
                const float It = (float) ft[index];
                AtA[0][0] += Ix * Ix;
                AtA[1][1] += Iy * Iy;
                AtA[0][1] += Ix * Iy;
                AtA[1][0] = AtA[0][1];
                Atb[0] += - Ix * It;
                Atb[1] += - Iy * It;
            }
            //Compute inverse of 2x2 array AtA: 1/(ad-bc)[[d -b][-c a]]
            const float det = AtA[0][0] * AtA[1][1] - AtA[0][1] * AtA[1][0];
            const float iAtA[2][2] = {
                {AtA[1][1] / det, - AtA[0][1] / det},
                {iAtA[0][1]     , AtA[0][0] / det}
                };
            //Compute optical flow : [Vx Vy] = inv[AtA] . Atb
            const float Vx = iAtA[0][0] * Atb[0] + iAtA[0][1] * Atb[1];
            const float Vy = iAtA[1][0] * Atb[0] + iAtA[1][1] * Atb[1]; 

            Mag[i + j * w] = hypotf(Vx, Vy); //sqrt(Vx²+Vy²)
        }
    }
    delete [] fy;   
    int max = *std::max_element(Mag.begin(), Mag.end());
    if(max == 0) 
        return;
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "maxMag = %i \n", max);

    //compute output which is Mag rescaled nothing interesting here.
}
```

My next step would be to complete the ***TODO*** comments.

Answer (score 3):

## `transpose()` makes a copy of its input

The first parameter of `transpose()` is passed by value, which means it makes a copy of `src` every time it is called. Pass it by `const` reference instead.

## Make functions really generic

You made `transpose()` and `conv()` templates. However, apart from templating the type of the input vector, the rest is still hardcoded. Consider making it even more generic:

```
template<typename InputRange, typename OutputIterator>
void transpose(const InputRange& src, OutputIterator dst, std::size_t w, std::size_t h) {
    auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(src), std::end(src));
    auto scale = static_cast<float>(std::numeric_limits<decltype(*dst)>::max())
                 / (*max - *min);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; i < h; ++i) {
            *dst++ = (src[w * j + i] - min) * scale;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it works for any kind of input and output, and it will scale correctly for the output type.
Note that you had a bug in your scaling: you forgot to subtract `min` from `max` before dividing.

You can do something similar for `conv()`. You might even want to do it for `LK_optical_flow()`.

## Use `std::size_t` for sizes, counts and indices

Instead of using `int`, prefer to use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for sizes, counts and indices. It's guaranteed to be the right size to be able to handle any size container.

## Create a function that combines convolution and transposition

You always call `transpose()` right after `conv()`, and you do this six times. It might be better to create a single functions that does the convolution and tranposition in one go.

## Create a `conv2D()` function

Create a function `conv2D()` that does an in-place two-dimensional convolution. Internally it could still use one-dimensional convolutions and transpositions, but it will simplify the code in `LK_optical_flow()`.

Also, while for larger kernels, a two-dimensional separable convolution is most efficiently done as two one-dimensional convolutions, here you just have a 3x3 convolution kernel. It might be faster to just implement a straightforward two-dimensional convolution, as this avoids the overhead of the transpositions.

## Other issues

- In `conv()`, why calculate the first `ng / 2 + 1` elements if you are going to immediately erase them?
- Use [`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) and [`std::copy_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead of `std::memset()` and `std::memcpy()`. It avoids having to use `sizeof`.
- Avoid manual memory management, just use a `std::vector<uin8_t>` for `fy`. Note that `std::vector` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that can copy data from another container, so you can just write:

  ```
  std::vector<uint8_t> fy(src1, src + w * h);
  ```
- Consider passing references to `std::vector`s to `LK_optical_flow()`, instead of raw pointers.
- To deallocate `tmp`, just make it go out of scope:

  ```
  {
      std::vector<int> tmp;
      tmp = conv(…);
      …
  }
  ```

  But it's not even necessary if you have a `conv2D()` function as mentioned above.
- Use [`std::hypot()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) instead of `hypotf()`. The former has overloads that will automatically use the right floating point size.